# Convert MYSQL RAW included hash(encrypt) query to Laravel eloquent query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

This is the raw query

```
"SELECT * FROM re_customer
WHERE LOWER(email) = '" . $input['email'] . "' 
AND 
  (password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $input['password'] . "'))))) 
   OR password = '" . md5( $input['password'] ) . "') 
AND status = '1'";
```

I tried

```
$customer = DB::connection( 'oc' )
              ->table( Customer::$customerTable )
              ->where( DB::raw( 'LOWER(email)' ), '=', mb_strtolower( $input['email'] ) )
              ->whereRaw( "(password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('?'))))) OR password = '?')", [
                  $input['password'],
                 md5($input['password'])
              ] )
              ->where( 'status', 1 )
              ->first();
```

But not working for me (both query results are not same). Can you please address me that what wrong on this query.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? I hope you don't try to implement security features like that.....

Comment: It means. first query is give expected result 2nd laravel query not give same like first one

Comment: You don't appear to be checking for the `md5` version in your second query.

Comment: Still not working. Is that right whereRaw segment @Rwd

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's a opencart query for validate login. I'm making API side for it. I want to validate login with same DB

Answer (score 0):

I solved the query conversion.

```
$customer = DB::connection( 'oc' )
              ->table( Customer::$customerTable )
              ->where( DB::raw( 'LOWER(email)' ), '=', mb_strtolower( $input['email'] ) )
              ->where( 'status', 1 )
              ->where( function ( $query ) use ( $input ) {
                  $query->whereRaw( "password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(?)))))", $input['password'] )
                        ->orWhere( 'password', '=', md5( $input['password'] ) );
              } )
              ->first();
```

this is working like a charm